# Sort file system data without using anything else than Prelude

Tags: sorting, haskell

I have defined a data type called FS the following way:

```
type Name= String

data Ext where { Txt::Ext ; Mp3::Ext ; Jar::Ext ; Doc::Ext ; Hs::Ext }
  deriving (Eq, Show)


data FS where {  A :: (Name,Ext) -> FS;
                 Dir :: Name-> [FS] -> FS }
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

(A stands for file and Dir for directory)
And I'm trying to make a function that given a `FS` (directory) it returns the same `FS` but ordered alphabetically at all levels, my attempt so far is the following:

```
orderFS :: FS-> FS
orderFS (Dir x y) = Dir x (map orderFS (sort y));
orderFS (A (x,y)) = A (x,y);
```

The only piece I'm missing is a function called "sort" that takes a `[FS]` and returns it ordered alphabetically by the `Name` field.
I read that there are functions like sort from `Data.List` that can help, but I have to do this without using anything else than `Prelude`.

So how should I implement such function? Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no `Name` field in `FS`. Your implementation of `orderFS` suggests you intend `FS` to be a union instead of a record?

Comment: I don't see any reason for this question, in its current form, to be downvoted.

Comment: @is7s, I suspect it's a reaction to the `Prelude`-only requirement, which tends to signal that the OP wants us to do their homework for them.

Comment: @dfeuer I don't understand what's with people getting pissed if a question comes from homework.. This is a site for people to ask questions on subjects they couldn't find the answer for, weather the question came from a homework problem, a text book or simply someone trying to code something in Haskell.
Yes, this question came to me from homework but instead of copying some quicksort code from the internet I rather ask here for an actual explanation on how the solution could be achieved.

Comment: @Chapi, the problem is not that the question arose in the process of you doing your homework. The problems is that you recognized that the key challenge was writing a sorting function, and then you stopped short. You give no indication of what your attempts to overcome this challenge looked like. If you'd posted a buggy or incomplete sorting routine, and explained why it was buggy or what trouble you were having completing it, then the question would have been much better received. Instead, you posted all sorts of irrelevant information about why you wanted a list-sorting function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe that there are any sorting functions in Prelude but not in a module like `Data.List`.  Note that `Data.List` is in the base package that is part of GHC, so in basically any situation where `Prelude` is available, I would imagine that `Data.List` would be as well---you shouldn't need to download/include any other packages in order to use it.

That said, if you do want to write your own sorting function, you are probably best off taking an existing simple sorting algorithm and using it.  There are very neat/simple ways of writing quicksorts and merge sorts in Haskell, although the obvious implementations sometimes don't have the same exact performance characteristics as you would expect.  Merge sort, for example, has roughly the same asymptotics, but partitioning the list into two actually takes some time, since the list is singly-linked and you therefore have to walk through half of it in order to split it.  But, it can be a very nice short function that looks a lot like the algorithm, and is probably worth doing as a learning exercise.

Also, I noticed that you are defining your `Ext` and `FS` types as GADTs, which I'm not really sure about the motivation for; I would suggest using the non-GADT syntax, which is much simpler for this example:

```
type Name = String
data Ext = Txt | Mp3 | Jar | Doc | Hs deriving (Eq, Show)
data FS = A Name Ext | Dir Name [FS] deriving (Eq, Show)
```

In order to sort them by name, it would probably be worth writing a simple accessor function that can get the name of an FS:

```
name :: FS -> Name
name (A   n _) = n
name (Dir n _) = n
```

Another approach would be to factor out the thing (Name) that is common to both cases:

```
data FS = NamedFS { name :: Name, fs :: UnnamedFS }
data UnnamedFS = A Ext | Dir [FS]
```

The first entry here uses record syntax, which, among other things, will automatically make a `name :: FS -> Name` accessor, as well as an `fs :: FS -> UnnamedFS`.

For the actual sort, it looks a lot like the algorithmic description of merge sort.  To start with, let's write a function to divide a list in two:

```
split :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
split xs = splitAt (length xs `div` 2) xs
```

We also need a function to merge two sorted lists:

```
merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge [] x = x
merge x [] = x
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) | x < y     = x:merge xs (y:ys)
                    | otherwise = y:merge (x:xs) ys
```

Actually, this is not what we want, because it always uses the `<` from the Ord instance; instead, we want something that takes in a comparison function.  In this case, we assume that if the comparison function returns true when called with x and y, x is conceptually less than y.

```
merge :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge _ [] x = x
merge _ x [] = x
merge le (x:xs) (y:ys) | x `le` y  = x:merge le xs (y:ys)
                       | otherwise = y:merge le (x:xs) ys
```

Now, we can implement mergesort like usual:

```
mergeSort :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
mergeSort _ []  = []
mergeSort _ [x] = [x]
mergeSort f l   = merge f (mergeSort f left) (mergeSort f right)
  where (left, right) = split l
```

And just call it like:

```
-- fss is some [FS]
mergeSort (\x y -> name x < name y) fss
```

If we could use `Data.Ord`, this could be further reduced to:

```
mergeSort (comparing name) fss
```

Answer (score 1):

The function in `Data.List` that could help you is [`sortOn`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortOn)
this together with a function `getName :: FS -> Name` would allow you to sort by comparing the `Name`s.

If you cannot use functions from `Data.List` you will have to implement a sorting algorithm yourself (of which there are many to choose from). One example is "QuickSort" as implemented in the [Learn you a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion#quick-sort) book:

```
quicksort :: [FS] -> [FS]
quicksort [] = []  
quicksort (x:xs) =   
    let smallerSorted = quicksort [a | a <- xs, getName a <= getName x]  
        biggerSorted = quicksort [a | a <- xs, getName a > getName x]  
    in  smallerSorted ++ [x] ++ biggerSorted
```

Note that I changed the comparisons to compare the `getName`s instead of the whole nodes.

Another thing: you are using GADT syntax to define your datatypes and I cannot see any reason for you to do so. Here is how I would write them instead using ordinary datatype declarations:

```
data Ext
  = Txt
  | Mp3
  | Jar
  | Doc
  | Hs
  deriving (Eq, Show)

data FS
  = File Name Ext
  | Dir Name [FS]
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Comment: I'm guessing the OP's class introduced the "GADT" syntax first; it's a lot more self-explanatory than the traditional syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the most natural list-sorting function in Haskell is the bottom-up mergesort (Peter Amidon's answer gives a top-down mergesort). Suppose you're starting with the list

```
[25,1,22,2,10,8,6,20,13,28,5,3,11]
```

The first step is to turn the list into a list of lists. The simplest way is with `map (:[])`, which yields

```
[[25],[1],[22],[2],[10],[8],[6],[20],[13],[28],[5],[3],[11]]
```

Next, you merge lists pairwise:

```
[[1,25],[2,22],[8,10],[6,20],[13,28],[3,5],[11]]
```

Repeat!

```
[[1,2,22,25],[6,8,10,20],[3,5,13,28],[11]]
```

And again!

```
[[1,2,6,8,10,20,22,25],[3,5,11,13,28]]
```

And once more:

```
[[1,2,3,5,6,8,10,11,13,20,22,25,28]]
```

As we now have just one list, we extract it.

---

To implement this, I think it's best to use a custom type for the lists of lists in this case, to express the appropriate strictness:

```
infixr 5 :::
data LL a = ![a] ::: LL a | Nil
```

Implementation proceeds step by step. While breaking the list up into singletons is the *simplest* way to start off the process, it's a bit wasteful and will slow down access to the first few elements. So let's go by pairs there too:

```
breakUp :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> LL a
breakUp _cmp [] = Nil
breakUp _cmp xs@[a] = xs ::: Nil
breakUp cmp (x1 : x2 : xs)
  | GT <- cmp x1 x2 = [x2,x1] ::: breakUp cmp xs
  | otherwise = [x1,x2] ::: breakUp cmp xs
```

Now we need to write a `merge` function:

```
merge :: (a -> a -> Ordering)
      -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge _cmp [] ys = ys
merge _cmp xs [] = xs
merge cmp xss@(x:xs) yss@(y:ys)
  | GT <- cmp x y = y : merge cmp xss ys
  | otherwise = x : merge cmp xs yss
```

Next we need to be able to merge a list of lists pairwise:

```
mergePairwise :: (a -> a -> Ordering)
              -> LL a -> LL a
mergePairwise _cmp Nil = Nil
mergePairwise _cmp xs@(_ ::: Nil) = xs
mergePairwise cmp (xs1 ::: xs2 ::: xss)
  = merge cmp xs1 xs2 ::: mergePairwise cmp xss
```

Then we must merge up until done:

```
mergeAll :: (a -> a -> Ordering)
         -> LL a -> [a]
mergeAll _cmp Nil = []
mergeAll _cmp (xs ::: Nil) = xs
mergeAll cmp xss = mergeAll cmp (mergePairwise cmp xss)
```

Now we're cooking with <strike>glass</strike> <strike>grass</strike> bass!

```
sortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
sortBy cmp = mergeAll cmp . breakUp cmp

sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
sort = sortBy compare
```

---

There's a bit of room to improve the above implementation by recognizing that the lists stored in the lists of lists are never empty. So we *might* get a small performance improvement using

```
data NonEmpty a = a :| [a]
data LL a = (:::) {-# UNPACK #-} !(NonEmpty a) (LL a) | Nil
```